# Parsing Columns and Identifying Fields in R

Tags: r, string, parsing

here is an example of my df:

```
data
276 '83 Rally '83 (1983) (V)\t\t\t\t1983
277 '87: A Love Story (2007)\t\t\t\t2007                                                                                                   
278 '88 Dodge Aries (2002)\t\t\t\t\t2002
279 '9': Acting Out (2009) (V)\t\t\t\t2009
```

I would like to create a data frame showing only the titles and the year. Does anyone have any advice on how to go about parsing this? I think I may need to split the columns on `\t\t\t\t`

```
     Title                Year 
276 '83 Rally '83     (1983) 
277 '87: A Love Story (2007)                                                                                             
278 '88 Dodge Aries   (2002)
279 '9': Acting Out   (2009)
```

Here is the dput

```
c("# (2014)\t\t\t\t\t\t2014", "#1 (2005)\t\t\t\t\t\t2005", "#1 (2009)\t\t\t\t\t\t2009", 
"#1 (2010)\t\t\t\t\t\t2010", "#1 (2010/I) (V)\t\t\t\t\t\t2010", 
"#1 (2010/II) (V)\t\t\t\t\t2010")
```

Comment: How many columns do you actually have at the moment? 1? [A `dput` would be helpful.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: Actually, the example that you give does not make the structure of your data.frame obvious.  Could you please provide your data in a way that shows the structure?  Please use `dput(df)` and paste the result into your question. If your data is very long, it will be fine to use `dput(head(df))`

Comment: @alistaire @G5W I only have one column named `data` at the moment. it contains strings of movie information (titles, dates released) 

Im not familiar with dput, but I ran this:  `dput(head(df))` and I will put output in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gsub():`

```
df$Title <- gsub("(.*?) \\(.*", "\\1", df$data)
df$Year  <- gsub(".*\\((\\d{4})\\).*", "\\1", df$data)

> df[c("Title", "Year")]
                  Title Year
1     276 '83 Rally '83 1983
2 277 '87: A Love Story 2007
3   278 '88 Dodge Aries 2002
4   279 '9': Acting Out 2009
```

Note: If `data` is actually a standalone vector, then just use it directly, e.g.

```
Title <- gsub("(.*?) \\(.*", "\\1", data)
```

Here is an explanation of the regex used to extract the year:

```
.*        match everything
\\(       up until the first parenthesis
(\\d{4})  then capture a four digit year
\\)       followed by a closing parenthesis
.*        consume the remainder of the string
```

The quantity `\\1` used as a replacement in `gsub()` uses the four digit year which was captured during the match.

Comment: Thank you. When I tried your code I got this error: `Error in df$data : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: It sounds like `data` isn't a data frame, it's just a vector of strings.  In this case just replace `df$data` with `data` in the code snippet I gave above.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed my data and its now in a df. Do you mind explaining your regex expression - specifically the regex used in 'df$year'